# ELMAH: Elmah pages not styled making them difficult to read

Tags: elmah, elmah.mvc

### Setup:

I have ELMAH installed via NuGet on an ASP.NET MVC 4 site.

On the dev machine the app is installed at the root.  It all works and is styled as ELMAH pages usually are.  It always does that, work on the dev machine I mean, doesn't it?

But on the server, the app installed in a sub folder (~/tracker).  Although ELMAH works fine, the pages are unstyled, making them difficult to read.

### Question:

What do I need to do to get the pages to style?

Presumably, the styling comes from a resource that can be configured in the web.config.  But how?

### Edit:

I have found that I am getting a highly relevant error:

```
System.Web.HttpException: A public action method 'stylesheet' was not found on controller 'Elmah.Mvc.ElmahController'.
```

The path is given as:

```
/tracker/elmah/stylesheet
```

This is obviously related to the Link tag in the source of the ELMAH pages:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/tracker/elmah/stylesheet" />
```

But how do I configure this url?

Answer (score 6):

What is your "elmah.mvc.route" setting?  Can you see the elmah screen if you remove "/tracker" from your path?

Out of the box, elmah's route setting is:

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
```

Yours needs to be

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="tracker/elmah" />
```

Your route configuration is correctly redirecting requests for controller actions, but elmah prints the stylesheet address itself without using your route config, so you'll need to tell it what route/URL to use for its references.