# Elmah.mvc - Alternate rooting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, elmah

I installed ELMAH.MVC nuget package and it's logging my ASP.NET MVC errors. However when I go to http://www.example.com/en-us/elmah the page is not styled and the below error is shown:

**A public action method 'stylesheet' was not found on controller 'Elmah.Mvc.ElmahController'.**

I have the following Routes:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("content/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");

        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "users",
        url: "{culture}/users/{userUrl}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "AccountProfile",
            action = "Index",
            culture = ""
        }
    );

        routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "SpecificCulture",
                        url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                        defaults: new
                        {
                            controller = "Home",
                            action = "Index",
                            id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                            culture = ""
                        }
                    );
    }
```

My web.config `appSettings`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="BaseAddress" value="http://localhost:3453/" />
    <add key="MailActive" value="true" />
    <add key="aspnet:UseHostHeaderForRequestUrl" value="true" />    
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="true" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="Administrator" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />  
</appSettings>
```

I believe the issue is on my routes, but sincerely I have no clue what to do about it.

Any help would be great

**EDIT** :

As sugested by Steve Newton I added the following route:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "elmah",
    url: "{controller}/elmah",
    defaults: new
        {
            controller = "elmah",
            action = "Index",
        }
    );
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [ELMAH: Elmah pages not styled making them difficult to read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875750/elmah-elmah-pages-not-styled-making-them-difficult-to-read)

Comment: The solution suggested by the other question don't solve my problem, so I guess it's a different root cause.

Comment: Per that other question, you tried modifying the config for Elmah?

Comment: I have no idea what to put on the ``elmah.mvc.route``.

Comment: Then how do you know that answer won't help you? By the way, I'd first try `<add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="en-us/elmah" />`. That's obviously not a pleasant thing if you have multiple cultures, but it would at least prove that that indeed does fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't express myself very clearly. I tried 2 or 3 different values but I got the same error. I also changed the ``<add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />`` to ``true``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a routing issue as described in the answer provided.  Why not leave the route config for Elmah as is (the key) and create a new route which allows example.com/elmah?  Elmah will not vary by culture and is a clean solution.

Comment: Can you please provide the code for the new route you suggest?